# how can I make view_slideshow module thumbnail pager scrollable?

Tags: 7, views

I am using the view_slideshow module.
When user goes to the property page(**Content type property**) I am showing the images using view slide_show module.
Main image is moving as a main slider image and thumbnail are being shown under the main image as thumbnail pager.

Now here is a problem:
Thumbnail pager is coming in a div its working fine if the number of images are 3-4.
But if the number of images are 8-10 then they are not being shown in the thumbnail pager div.I want to make the thumbnail pager div scrollable with arrow buttons on both end.

So if user clicks on the next arrow of thumbnail pager then that thumbnail will comes into the thumbnail pager div.

Thanks

Comment: I need the same thing. did you ever figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

[Views Slideshow JCarousel](https://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow_jcarousel) will suits your problem description best . Before Installing it you need to have [views](https://drupal.org/project/views) and [views slideshow](https://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow)  enabled.One extra work you need to do is to create two folders in sites/all/libraries folder

1) sites/all/libraries/**jcarousel** - download the .tar file from https://codeload.github.com/jsor/jcarousel/legacy.tar.gz/0.2.9 and extract here.

2) sites/all/libraries/**jquery.cycle** - save here the .js file you get form http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle.all.js link.

Now .

- create a view of content of TEST (let here be the content type is TEST).
- Select Format slide show and click settings . Now in Bottom Widget(you can select top widget also) check the pager checkbox.
- It will ask all the requirements like *Number of visible pager item* and *scroll items* . Save it and you are done.